# SharePoint Designer 2013- Removal of 'Design View'

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, web-part, sharepoint-online

I am trying to understand the difference between SharePoint Designer 2010 & SharePoint Designer 2013.

Found this blog by Asif Rehmani: [Click here for the blog.](http://blog.sharepoint-videos.com/sharepoint-designer-2013-data-view-web-part-list-view-web-part-design-view-is-gone/)

He has explained the differences of SP2010 & SP2013 Designer, along with the removal of 'Design View' in SP2013 Designer.

Is that the Design View in SharePoint Designer 2013 never going to come back?

If anybody has the latest update on this please share..

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't coming back, ever. I had a [more recent] link from MS explaining it in more detail than the below one, but I can't find it. SPD will basically be used to create workflows. Any HTML editor can be used to mock up content now. Really stinks because other HTML editors are not Sharepoint aware so it'll be more difficult to create things like data view web parts as easily as they can be created now.

http://blogs.office.com/b/sharepoint/archive/2012/10/10/changes-to-the-design-view-in-sharepoint-designer-2013.aspx